# How can I create multiple scenes in Flash Builder 4/AS3?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, automation, flashbuilder4

Is it even possible? Working with just AS3 files in FB4, can I just somehow attach a new Scene object to the root scene?

Comment: @ExitFailure what The_asMan said, also why would you want to do that in the first place?

Comment: Why would you use a Scene object ? Any particular functionality not supported by DisplayObjects ?

Comment: And I spent days looking for and trying out many, w/o results. Basically, I need to go from swf (which dynamically pulls from db) to flv, with the entire process automated (including the compilation of swf). Currently I am using Flash Builder 4 since it allows me to do the command line compilation (mxmlc), but working in fb4 I don't have access to a timeline and as such my videos are made purely in as3, so the frame count is always 1.

Comment: Why can't you just compile from command line and output the flv?

Comment: Well, actually I do not see an flv output odd I thought there was a way to do this easy

Comment: Come to think about it SWf(as3 driven) to flv can not be done. Any time you convert to flv the data can not be dynamic. the converting process will only go frame by frame which of course is impossible with a data driven swf.

Comment: Hmm, that sucks... Ok, so I see are 5 potential solutions I could try and pursue. 1) Find a converter that can convert an x second long .swf into a .flv (x would be the same for all videos, so automating it shouldn't be an issue). 2) Increase the frame count in as3 file in FB4. I ran across a very interesting class that almost gave me what I needed, but in the end I wasn't able to get it working. Link for the curious (http://etcs.ru/pre/ClipFactory/srcview/). Still potentially holding out for a solution here. Can FB4 emulate timelines? 3) Figure out how to batch compile projects in Flash CS5.5

Comment: 4) Find a program that records my mouse movements and keystrokes and use it to manage the starting and stopping of the manual file conversion process. This is probably what I will have to end up doing. 5) Find a way to embed straight up .swf files into my site. This will likely not be an acceptable solution, I feel, but if it's practical, they may not have a choice. I'm at the point where I can automate the entire process up to creating all the .swf files, btw. Such a small step away from my goal, and yet I'm stuck :(

Answer (score 0):

It is not common to use the Scene object in flash. Usually you would just have Movieclips that you add and remove from the stage.